# Apache HttpClient response content length returns -1

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

Why does the following Code returns -1? Seems that the request failed.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.de");

    HttpResponse response;
    try
    {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        // Prints -1
        System.out.println(entity.getContentLength());
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        httpGet.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

And is it possible to get the response as String?

Comment: Javadoc for `getContentLength`: _the number of bytes of the content, or a negative number if unknown._

Comment: Javadoc : http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent()

Comment: Well documented... Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need the content length to begin with? It will be better consuming the response content (probably the `InputStream`) instead of *validating* the response through this mechanism.

Comment: *is it possible to get the response as String?* yes. Try something instead of asking *the codez*.

Comment: I didn't want any code.

Comment: Then you have your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running

```
Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
for (Header header : headers) {
    System.out.println(header);
}
```

It will print

```
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 19:10:04 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=dad7e2356ddb3b7a:FF=0:TM=1378840204:LM=1378840204:S=vQcLzVPbOOTxfvL4; expires=Thu, 10-Sep-2015 19:10:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.de
Set-Cookie: NID=67=S11HcqAV454IGRGMRo-AJpxAPxClJeRs4DRkAJQ5vI3YBh4anN3qS0EVeiYX_4XDTGN-mY86xTBoJ3Ncca7eNSdtGjcaG31pbCOuqsZEQMWwKn-7-6Dnizx395snehdA; expires=Wed, 12-Mar-2014 19:10:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.de; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

This is not a problem, the page you requested simply doesn't provide a `Content-Length` header in its response. As such, the `HttpEntity#getContentLength()` returns `-1`.

[`EntityUtils`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) has a number of methods, some of which return a `String`.

---

Running `curl` more recently produces

```
> curl --head http://www.google.de
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 15:38:18 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2020-04-03-15; expires=Sun, 03-May-2020 15:38:18 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.de; Secure
Set-Cookie: NID=201=H8GdKY8_vE5Ehy6qSkmQru13HqdGEj2tvZUFqvTDAVBxFoL4POI0swPtfI45v1TBjrJuAAfbcNMUddniIf9HHituCAFwUqmUFMDwxDYK5qUlcWiB1A64OcGp6PTT6LKur2r_3z-ToSvLf8RZhKWdny6E8SaArMpkaOqUEWp4aoQ; expires=Sat, 03-Oct-2020 15:38:18 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.de; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

The headers contain a `Transfer-Encoding` value of `chunked`. With [`chunked`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6), the response contains "chunks" preceded by their length. An HTTP client uses those to read the entire response.

The [HTTP Specification states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-33) that the `Content-Length` header should not be present when `Transfer-Encoding` has a value of `chunked` and MUST be ignored if it is.

Comment: @Accountantم These are unrelated issues. For `"http://www.google.de"`, as you can see from the headers above (still true today, check with `curl`), the response is returned with a `Transfer-Encoding` of `chunked`. With `chunked`, a `Content-Length` does not need to be sent (and in fact the [HTTP 1/1 Specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-33) mandates it's ignored if both headers are present). A length is present in each chunk. That's what the HTTP client uses to read the entire response. But it's not a header so it's not available.

Comment: @Accountantم I edited my answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 4):

Please notice that response header name Transfer-Encoding. Its value is chunked which means data is deliveryed block by block. Transfer-Encoding: chunked and Content-Length does not turn out at the same time.
There are two reason.

1. Server does not want sent content length.
2. Or server do not know the content length when it flush a big size data whose size is large than server's buffer.

So when there is no content length header, you can find the size of each chunked block before body of content. For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8A7461DDA53B4C4DD0E89D73219CB5F8; Path=/

Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 07:10:05 GMT

11

helloworld!

3

123

0
```

Above headers and content tell us, there are two block data. The size of first block is 11. the size of second block is 3. So the content length is 14 at all.

regards,
Xici

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get the content length without caring about the content, you can do this.

EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpResponse.getEntity()).length

Comment: What if I want to get both, the content and its length?